# Why does the result show me time in days rather than time of day (ex. 23:09)

Tags: r, time, mean

I would like to know the mean of the sleep time but since there are times after midnight it seems to give me the mean as time in days, how would I be able to convert this to 24 hour time?

```r
data <- read.table(text="
sleep_time wake_time
23:30:00 03:30:00
23:50:00 06:00:00
00:50:00 07:30:00
00:30:00 06:25:00
00:20:00 06:00:00
23:00:00 06:00:00
00:10:00 05:00:00
", header=T)

mean(times(data$wake_time))
# [1] 05:46:26

mean(times(data$sleep_time))
# [1] 10:18:34

wake <- times(data$wake_time)

sleep <- times(data$sleep_time)

times(mean(ifelse(sleep < wake, sleep + 1, sleep)))
# Time in days:
# [1] 1.000992
```

Comment: Can you please specify what library the `times()` function is from (chron?) by adding a `library()` call to your code?

Comment: @zephryl has been nice to format your question properly. It's your second post, please be respectful. `library(chron)` seems to be used (such as in your other post).  chron document specify that arithmetic is in day. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/chron.pdf

My suggestion is to add one hour (1/24 day), use modular math `%%1` so all times would be around midnight- 2AM,  compute `mean()` and substract back one hour. 

 `mean( (times(data$sleep_time)+1/24) %%1 ) -1/24`

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package, but if the result of your last line is a difftime object, or coercible to one, you could use `as.numeric(result, unit = "hours")` or `as.numeric(as.difftime(result), unit = "hours")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the chron package then `"times"` objects are intended to represent the times in date/times as opposed to durations; however, we can get the effect anyways by extracting the days and times part separately and pasting them together.   If `tt` is the result of the last line of code in the question and the objective is to display a string showing the number of days, hours:minutes:seconds then determine the number of days and create a string showing that and what remains after subtracting it off.  (Note that this will round to the nearest second should there be fractions of a second.)

```
library(chron)

days <- as.integer(tt)
paste(days, tt - days)
## [1] "1 00:01:26"
```

Comment: To be able to then get the standard deviation of the sleep_times (if those sleep_times include times after midnight, I have been using `sd(ifelse(sleep < wake, sleep+1, sleep) * 24*60)` but for the specific times I am using the avg sleep time after running the code provided is 00:19 with and SD=37.6 derived from the code above would this be correct and interpreted as the timing of sleep varies by 38 minutes

Comment: If you are looking to compute circular means and sd's  then look at the circular package.